# How does the CImg hough implementation work?

Tags: c++, image-processing, hough-transform, cimg

[Here is the example Hough Transform from the CImg library](https://github.com/dtschump/CImg/blob/master/examples/hough_transform2d.cpp)

I'm trying to figure out how this implementation works, since it is so much different from the other ones you might find online.

As I understand it, for a Hough transform you need to loop through every edge point and calculate 180 degrees of rho/theta values to populate the field.

But in the CImg implementation, when you press space, the programs just loops through every pixel and calculates the rho/theta once and in the end it still generates a correct result.

I'm trying to implement this on my own without the aid of any libraries but I can't figure out how this works. I think the "magic" happens between the 2 gradient images taken before the loop, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double
  gx = grad[0](x,y),
  gy = grad[1](x,y);
double
  theta = std::atan2(gy,gx);
```

Calculates the direction of the gradient. This way we get the theta without looping through 180° for each point.

I think it's basically a Sobel operation:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator